# Seeking within different streams in DirectShow

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

In an application which I develop I play several layers of video using VMR9. The problem is that I need to be able to navigate within each video stream independently.

Has anyone implemented something similar or know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter graphs are not supposed to be seeked partially. You should break them into separate graphs and combine content using certain method that passed data between the graphs, such as in master-slave manner. One of the popular approaches is to use "bridges": [Multiple Graphs in DirectShow](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/).